# GASでスプレッドシートの特定のセルの値にハイパーリンクが設定されているか判定する方法

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

例えばA列に文字列が入っているデータがあり
画像のように途中まではリンクが設定されているとしたときに
リンクが設定されていない文字列だけにハイパーリンクを設定していくようなスクリプトが組みたいと思っております。

色々、調べてはみたのですが、リンクが設定されているかの判定をする方法がわからず
お判りになるかたがいれば、教えてください。

※数字は適当です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

こちらでリンクを取得できるのは、リンクのテキストが数値でない時のようです。

```
const linkUrl = sheet.getRange('Q4').getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl();
```

リンクのテキスト欄を文字列にすると上のメソッドでURLを取得できますが、
リンクのテキスト欄が数値のときは、.getRichTextValue()のところで値がnullになり、.getLinkUrl()でエラーになります。
なので、事前にセル範囲の表示形式を文字列に変えておく必要があります。
表示形式が書式なし文字列のときは、
.getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl()の値はリンクでないならnullになります。

ということでリンクかどうかを取得するスクリプトの例は次のようになります。

```
//単一または複数のセル範囲がリンクかどうかを取得
//戻り値:単一セル → true or false 複数セル→ true or false の配列
function isLinkUrl(range) {
  const formats = range.getNumberFormats();
  range.setNumberFormat('@');
  const rows = range.getRichTextValues();
  const results = rows.map((r) => r.map((c) =>
    c.getLinkUrl() !== null
      ? true
      : false
  ));
  range.setNumberFormats(formats);
  if (results.length == 1 && results[0].length == 1) {
    return results[0][0];
  } else if (results.length > 0) {
    return results;
  }
}
//動作確認
function confirmLink() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getRange('Q4:Q14');
  const values = isLinkUrl(range);
  console.log(values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

理想的な解決策ではないと思いますが、リンク判定部分はこちらのサイトのコードが参考になるかと思います
[【GASで便利に】シート内の全てのリンクを抽出する](https://myfunc.jp/items/00039/index.html)